# Database field encryption

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, encryption

I need to store some user data in one server database. It is not sensitive data, but neither I or other users should get access to this content. I want the owner to be confident that even I or other developers will not be able to read his data querying the database.

Tables structure will be like this: (ID | Data) where Data should contain an encrypted JSON string.

I would like to do encryption/decryption on the client, using a secret key that would not persisted anywhere (user should keep this password or otherwise he would not be able to get his data anymore).

Do you see any pitfall in this approach?

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2431/sql-server-column-level-encryption-example-using-symmetric-keys/)

Comment: SQL encryption is good, but given the nature of this question, I'm going to go out on a limb here and say Alessandro, is probably an sa on the SQL server or that the customer doesn't even want the SA to be able to see said data.  With that said, I've used client encrypted strings and binary data before, the biggest thing to remember is that any good encryption algorithm will have an output larger than the input, so you'll need to do some testing around how large to make the columns for the data you're storing.

Comment: Yes MBulava, that's the question. No problem about data size, all encrypted field will be varchar(MAX).